# "On the third floor stood a salesman with [number] artificial legs"

Tags: prepositions

> On the third floor stood a salesman with *one* artificial leg.
>
> On the third floor stood a salesman with *two* artificial legs.
>
> On the third floor stood a salesman with *three* artificial legs.
>
> On the third floor stood a salesman with *four* artificial legs.

I'm not sure whether the preposition *with* can be interpreted as 'in possession of' or 'characterized by' and whether the interpretation can be influenced by the number of legs.

I did an exhaustive and exhausting search before asking here, but search results suggest that the interpretation depends on what the relation is between the 'salesman' and the 'legs' and I don't understand how this can be helpful  on the linguistic plan.

Can anybody explain, please?

Comment: The only decisive factor in this ambiguity is context, I'd say, so the syntax tells you nothing, not even with four legs, or a thousand.

Comment: Thus the proverbial "1000 words to describe a picture". This isn't much different from the sentence, "It was dark." in that it requires other sentences around it to establish what *it* is, and what kind of *dark* is being discussed.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Is it "Is 'with' ambiguous?" ? Yes, it is. Do you speak a language in which there are two different unambiguous words for the two ideas? Also, exactly what kind of search did you do?

Comment: This question can be improved by showing the actual results of research, rather than just claiming research was done.

Answer (score 8):

Well, your problem is that it's ambiguous, mostly the first sentence. When I first read the sentences, I thought he was wearing two artificial legs. Then I read the next two sentences and I thought "Wait hold on!" People only have two legs. I reread it slowly and realized you meant carrying two, three, and four, legs, respectively. Then I was plain confused what you meant.

To remove this ambiguity, we must rephrase.

> On the first floor stood a salesman *carrying* two artificial legs.

> On the first floor stood a salesman *wearing* two artificial legs.

The meaning is now clear. No more creepy three-legged salesmen.

Comment: However, the ambiguity may be intentional. Such things are the basis of humour and word-play.

Comment: Only when a sentence is taken out of context is this kind of ambiguity a problem. In context, people are usually very capable of resolving semantic ambiguity.

Comment: The sentences would have made more sense if their order was reversed.  That way, one could at least presume the salesman was having a good day selling his artificial legs.

Comment: @J.R. It cannot be such a 'good day' for him if a salesman had to be  selling **his** artificial legs -- that would be his last resort when he is broke. [Problems of resolving semantic ambiguity?]